# How to Set Object to null

Tags: c#, oop

Why `c = null` does not work in the following code?

```
public class Sample{
        public int c;
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Sample c = new Sample();
            Console.WriteLine(c.c);
            f(c);
            Console.WriteLine(c.c);
            g(c);
            Console.WriteLine(c.c);
        }

        static void f(Sample c){
            c.c = 2;
        }
        static void g(Sample c){
            c = null;
        }
    }
```

The output is 0, 2 and 2, while I expect the null for the last output.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-reference-type-parameters

Comment: Because you output `c.c` while you update the value of the local parameter `c`. Assigning a parameter inside a method will not affect its value outside of the function

Comment: The *reference* to `Sample` is *copied*. You assign null to the *copied* `Sample` reference, which does not affect the original reference.

Comment: Search for "reference and value types" and "pass by reference/value".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because reference to Sample is copied so null is assigned to the copied reference and original reference does not changed.
if you want to change original reference you should pass it by reference:

```
        static void g(ref Sample c)
        {
            c = null;
        }
```

....

```
        g(ref c);
```

Comment: You mean, Classes are not by ref by default?

Comment: see it-> https://codewala.net/2016/05/22/passing-a-reference-type-using-ref-keyword/

Comment: @MohsenJafari classes are reference types (meaning that a variable contains a reference to the object, not the object itself), but by default this reference is passed by value. See http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html